I have a formula for the number of spanning subgraphs of a complete graph
Assume we have a complete graph $G$ that has $n$ nodes. The number of connected spanning trees of $G$ is given by $n^{(n-2)}$. We know that since $G$ is complete it got $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges. Since a spanning tree has $n-1$ edges, after deriving a spanning tree out of a complete graph there will remain $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-(n-1)$ unused edges. The unused edges can be added to each spanning tree in $2^{[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-(n-1)]}$ different ways. So, to compute the total number of spanning subgraphs of $G$ I can simply multiply the number of possible spanning trees (i.e., $n^{(n-2)})$ by $2^{[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-(n-1)]}$. Thus,
The total number of connected spanning subgraphs of complete graph $G$= $n^{(n-2)}2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-(n-1)}$=$n^{(n-2)}2^{\frac{1}{2}(n-1)(n-2)}$.
My questions:

Is this formula correct?
If so, why is it bigger than $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$, which is the total number of subgraphs of $G$?


The sequence you are looking for is listed on OEIS as A001187. The listing doesn't look like there is a closed formula.

I would have thought that the number of spanning subgraphs of $K_n$ is $2^{n(n-1)/2}$, and the total number of subgraphs of $K_n$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk2^{k(k-1)/2}$. What is your definition of "spanning subgraph"? Isn't a spanning subgraph of $G$ a subgraph of $G$ with the same vertex set?

Your formula is not correct, you are counting some subgraphs multiple times.
Your strategy chooses a spanning tree first and then adds a subset of the remaining edges. There usually is another way (or even lots of other ways) to choose the same subgraph by starting with another spanning tree. Suppose, for example, $T$ and $T'$ are two disjoint spanning trees. The spanning subgraph $T \cup T'$ can be obtained by choosing the spanning tree $T$ and then adding the edges from $T'$. It can also be obtained by taking $T'$ as the spanning tree and then adding the edges from $T$. An even more extreme example is the full subgraph. In order to generate it, you may choose any of the $n^{n-2}$ spanning trees and adding all of the remaining edges on top. This single spanning subgraph is counted $n^{n-2}$ times, when you only want to count it once.
